# Matrices - Inverse of the principal square root of a covariance matrix (^-1/2)

Tags: matrices, statistics, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, covariance

Say you have a square (variance)covariance matrix S

How would one go about working S^-1/2 (inverse of the principle square)?

Bearing in mind, I'm trying to understand a paper which states:

[image: I = S^-1/2 such that I(transposed) * I = S^-1]

I've tried multiple suggestions, such as:

- square root, then take the inverse of the square root: [Inverse Square Root Of Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230051/inverse-square-root-of-matrix)
- reciprocal of the square root of each term in the diagonal: [Raising a square matrix to a negative half power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340321/raising-a-square-matrix-to-a-negative-half-power)
- plus tried (^-1/2) directly on multiple online matrix calculators

However, none of them seem to hold true for the latter part of the what's stated on the paper.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the square root of a matrix M using the [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), M = LL'. Then compute the inverse of L.

Comment: What is the inverse square root actually is? If $S =ULU^T$ then why $S^{-1/2} =UL^{-1/2}U^T$

Answer (score 0):

@Avv, if $S=U L U^{T}$, then $S^{-1}=(U L U^{T})^{-1} = U L^{-1} U^{T} = U L^{-1/2} L^{-1/2} U^{T} = U L^{-1/2} U^T U L^{-1/2} U^{T} = (U L^{-1/2} U^T) (U L^{-1/2} U^{T})$,

thus $S^{-1/2} = U L^{-1/2} U^T$

Note that $U$ is orthonormal, and $L$ is diagonal